# Classical and weak derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $\Omega\in R^{n}$, does $u\in H^{1}(\Omega)$ imply the classical derivative of order $1$ exists a.e.? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, let $\Omega$ be the unit ball and let $\alpha > 0.$ Define $u(x) = |x|^{-\alpha}$. Then $u$ is unbounded in a neighborhood of $0$, and $|Du(x)| = \alpha |x|^{-\alpha -1}$ so that $$ \int_\Omega |Du(x)|^2 \, dx = \int_\Omega |x|^{-2(\alpha + 1)} \, dx  < \infty$$ provided that $\alpha < \frac n2 - 1$ (if $n = 2$ you may need to work with $u(x) = \log |x|$ instead). If $\{r_k\}$ is an enumeration of the rational points in $\Omega$ you can consider the function $$v(x) = \sum_k 2^{-k} u(x - r_k).$$ This is unbounded in a neighborhood of every point in $\Omega$ and is therefore nowhere continuous, yet belongs to $H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Nice counter examples Umberto. Thank you very much. Grateful to you